# VoIP Software for small business that allows numbers from other countries

Tags: voip

So I'm at a bit of a loss here, my father has recently moved to Germany due to his parent's health. However his business is still based in Canada and he wants to keep a North American phone number, this could be Canadian or American, but the number his customers call and see when he calls, should be with the +1 country code.

His business is small, with 2 employees, so we don't need any large solution. I had originally considered Skype with a dedicated number, but just saw that they discontinued the registration of these numbers since October 12th.

Does anyone know a software that could be used for this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a possibility of using a local installation in the US via [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol)? If eg. you are still there, you could offer him access to your installation then.

Comment: Is the solution you're looking for to be used primarily by him on his cell phone? If so, I would suggest looking into something like google voice, which allows you to port an existing phone number to google's voip solution for (I believe) a one time fee of $20. https://support.google.com/voice/answer/1065667?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some affordable web-based software like [CrazyCall](https://www.crazycall.com/?utm_source=softwarerecs.stackexchange.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=hza). It's a simple online calling application that offers local phone numbers from different countries worldwide, including those, from North America and Canada. The first number is free, but you'll need to pay $10/month per seat ($20 in total per month in your case).

Since it's web-based, your father and his employee need to have just a computer with Internet connection and headsets to use it. Once the phone number is chosen, it will be possible to take incoming and make outbound calls using that number. In my personal opinion, it's much cheaper than Skype when it comes to international calling, but you can try it free for 14 days and see if works good in your case.